# What does the inscription on Mjolnir exactly mean?

Tags: marvel, weapon, thor-marvel

A side of the Hammer is inscribed with: *"Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor."*

Does this mean that, if found worthy, you'll become [Thor-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_%28Marvel_Comics%29#Powers_and_abilities) or just acquire the [abilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mjolnir_%28comics%29#Powers_and_abilities) granted to Thor by Mjolnir?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The answer varies by interpretation of the writer. Different writers have chosen to interpret it in a variety of ways. Some transfer the powers, some just allowed Mjolnir to be lifted.**

Examples include:

We have seen people become Thor (the crippled [Donald Blake](http://marvel.wikia.com/Donald_Blake_%28Earth-616%29) became Thor). This was later rewritten to be a mortal body created by Odin to teach Thor humility.

[image]

[Eric Masterson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderstrike_%28Eric_Masterson%29) was an EMT who was merged with the power of Thor by Odin when Eric was mortally injured as a bystander near a battle where Thor was involved. Later when Thor was thought to have killed Loki, Masterson was deemed worthy and retained the power of Thor and Mjolnir becoming Thor and even serving as an Avenger.

[image]

Thor later is released from banishment and Masterson gets his own hammer and codename: Thunderstrike. Thunderstrike is later killed in battle destroying the Bloodaxe.

We have seen the acquisition of Thor-like power such as [Beta-Ray Bill](http://marvel.wikia.com/Beta_Ray_Bill_%28Earth-616%29). Beta-Ray later gets his own hammer Storm Breaker. Beta-Ray was an alien who acquired the full powers of Thor and still retains them today.

[image]

We have seen people simply lift the hammer of Thor and no powers are transferred. Captain America was one such person.

> When you first spoke to me about your problems, I had doubts...about
> you. They were quickly erased...when you lifted Mjolnir...for only a
> man or god worthy -- pure of heart and noble of mind -- could have
> done so! ... A sacred bond unites all those who have e'er been
> privileged to wield Mjolnir! A bond which stretches far into infinity!
> I salute you, Captain! **--Thor Vol 1, Issue #390**

Others lifting it in canon include: Erik Masterson, Beta-Ray Bill, Odin, Bor (Thor's grandfather) and Buri/Tiwaz, Thor's great-grandfather.

Several sentient machines have also lifted it (non-sentient machines cannot): [Gabriel Lan, the Airwalker and herald of Galactus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air-Walker), Zarrko the Tomorrow Man's mining robot, and the [Awesome Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_Android) by imitating Thor's abilities and worthy nature.

[image]

Comment: There was also an issue of _What If_ in which Jane Foster found Thor's hammer instead of Donald Blake, gained the powers of Thor, and started calling herself [Thordis](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix/thordis.htm).

Comment: I tried not to add the non-canon (What If?) stories to keep the list relatively short. This would include: Conan the Barbarian; Dargo Ktor (Future Thor); Loki; Magni; Rogue (after absorbing the entirety of Thor's life force and thus essentially becoming Thor);Miguel O'Hara (Spider-Man 2099); Woden; Alex Power; and the DC Comics characters Superman (though he was unable to later that issue and Thor claimed Odin had briefly lifted the enchantment) and Wonder Woman.

Comment: It might be worth adding Jane Foster to the list, since she has wielded the power of Thor for the last several years in Earth-616 continuity.

Answer (score 4):

Thor #340 reveals that when Thor loses the hammer for 60 seconds, he reverts to mortal form. There have been several besides Thor who have been able to wield Mjolnir, Captain America for example (Thor #390).

They don't become Thor, but they wield the power of Thor, which is Mjolnir the epic hammer. Note that during times that others wield Thor, by the same enchantment previously noted, Thor loses his "Thor powers".

To clarify, when Captain America got Thor's hammer, he didn't get Thor's strength, he only had the abilities of Mjolnir. During this time Thor's strength was gone, but as soon as Cap' tossed the hammer back to him, his strength came back and he mashed his opponent through an island (that had water under it...).

Comment: but see Beta Ray Bill.

Comment: 'Looses' or 'Loses'? There's a pretty big difference there.

Comment: Corrected grammar. I believe that since the powers don't always transfer, it's like one of the conditions, instead of a cup bearing the ability. Odin grants the power, on condition that he holds Mjolnir. Beta Ray Bill seems to have been granted extra powers from Odin outside of the enchantment, as he doesn't need Mjolnir to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC it actually provides both to the bearer.  Specifically in the instance of [Beta-Ray Bill](http://marvel.wikia.com/Beta_Ray_Bill_%28Earth-616%29) and the other members of the [Thor Corps](http://marvel.wikia.com/Thor_Corps_%28Earth-616%29)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it says that only those who are worthy may wield the hammer, although I don't know why Hela could destroy it because she is simply not worthy.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question.