# Has Galactus ever been depicted attempting to lift Mjolnir?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mjolnir, galactus

I was reading [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/79402/20557) and it got me to thinking - Galactus is a being driven solely by need, with no moral or ethic quandaries about what he does, and no malice or "evil" is driving his actions. He is also the size of a planet, and could probably push a small moon out of orbit if needed. That said, he would also probably never have a reason to pick up a tiny little weapon like Mjolnir... but perhaps he could if he wanted to, either through sheer strength or by his nature falling within Odin's definition of "worthy".

**Has Galactus ever been depicted attempting to lift or move Mjolnir (Thor's hammer)?** I'm putting the comics tag, but any continuity or medium will do, as long as Galactus is shown picking up (or trying and failing to pick up) the hammer - not necessarily to wield it as a weapon, but just to move it at the very least.

Comment: How could he possibly pick it up? It would be like one of us trying to pick up an atom.

Comment: I feel like this fits within a meme... "Galactus doesn't bother picking up Mjolnir. Instead, he moves the universe so that Mjolnir comes to him."

Comment: If Thor drops his hammer in Galactus hand, could Galactus move said hand with said hammer around?

Comment: @Daft he's not that big. Galactus is only 28 feet on average, in 616

Comment: @cde Read the question: _He is also the size of a planet, and could probably push a small moon out of orbit if needed_. Sounds big to me.

Comment: @cde I just checked and the Marvel wiki does indeed list his height at 29 feet. I'm inclined to think that's a typo, however, since to my knowledge he's never been depicted that small. The horns on top of his helmet alone are typically much larger than 30 feet, although it DOES say that his size changes according to his hunger. In every depiction of Galactus I've ever seen, he's at least Unicron-sized if not larger.

Comment: @cde If Thor dropped Mjolnir on a small moon, could Galactacus still move that moon?

Comment: During the John Byrne run of Fantastic Four, Galactus was depicted to shrink as his own life energy was running out. He was pretty small toward the end (~20 feet IIRC).

Comment: @Daft "If Thor was holding Mjoinir, could Galactus move Thor?" *That* at least we know for sure.  People knock Thor around all the time while he's holding Mjolnir.

Comment: @Daft Yeah, I think that's the dividing line. Generally it's lifting Mjolnir that's shown to be difficult, but the line is "whosoever *holds* this hammer..."  I suppose that means that basic movement (such as a vehicle or the motion of a planet) is unaffected, it's only people who try to directly *hold* it who are stopped.

Comment: Galactus is depicted differently on Covers and in different mediums, but main universe marvel 616 he is 28ft by canon. If Galactus was the size of a Planet and can push a moon, he could never set foot on Earth because his gravitational force would destroy it, let alone his foot step.

Comment: Has Galactus ever actually "set foot" on Earth? That might make for another interesting question - I've only seen him in space or hovering. And in those cases, the good guys are always miniscule next to him. I think the smallest I've ever seen him drawn was in Marvel Zombies, but even then he was big enough that the Hulk would fit in his mouth whole.

Comment: **But let's stop wasting time on Galactus variable sizing, as that doesn't really matter to the crux of the question, which is can A force of Nature like Galactus, or the Living Tribunal, or Ego the living planet lift/move/wield mjolnir.**

Comment: I always thought Galactus' size was dependent on how large he wanted to be, as he would still have all of his powers at any size. Actually the best thing showing this is in the video game Marvel vs Capcom 3 as he's the final boss, the fight itself takes place in space but at the start he his shown bigger than earth itself but then he shrinks down to the 20-30ft size for the fight. Also I want to add that Galacutus also looks different depending who views him for example when the skulls see Galactus he looks like a skrull not the human version.

Comment: @daft I don't know of a single instance where there was an example of a difference between wield and lift.

Comment: Guys, keep in mind that I'm trying to find an example of this event being depicted in some form of media - comics, cartoon, whatever. It's turning into a bit of a debate, which it probably shouldn't be.

Comment: @Omegacron yeah going off topic in a big way. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Omegacron Check out [this q/a](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16407/what-does-the-inscription-on-mjolnir-exactly-mean)

Comment: You won't find any images of Galactus "wielding" Mjolnir. If there were any, I would have them or have seen them. As to whether he could, the answer is yes, since Galactus is far more powerful than Odin and the "enchantments" Odin uses would be able to be overcome with brute scientific force on Galactus' part. Using the "Power Cosmic" he has created beings as powerful as Thor. It is very likely the enchantments used by Odin are within his ability to create/replicate/duplicate/eliminate if he so wishes. Odin is a powerful being, almost as powerful as Galactus. But Galactus is a force of nature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly I'm almost certain that Galactus directly lifting or wielding Mjolnir hasn't yet been depicted. So we'll have to go back to how the hammer was made and how its magic works. The hammer was made from uru metal and enchanted by Odin whose  [enchantments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17199/what-will-happen-to-the-enchantment-of-worthiness-on-mjolnir-after-the-death-o) would be backed by the Odin force which is one of the most powerful things in the marvel universe. Now in order to wield Mjolnir you must either be found worthy or have the strength to overpower Odin's enchantments which would be a impossible feat for most anyone.

Galactus himself like the OP mentioned isn't exactly evil well this is true but it goes further than that. Galactus as long as he isn't hungry is a rather peaceful entity, even more so he exists for the purpose of recreating the universe when its time comes, like he did the last time he does feel some remorse for the planets he eats in the same way people might about eating cattle. So it could be a toss up if Galactus is actually worthy or not everything he does is to keep the universe alive, and facilitate the creation of the next one. I got this Galactus info from the [marvel wiki page](http://marvel.com/universe/Galactus)

Now the worthiness may not actually matter if Galactus is strong enough to break Odin's enchantment which is another one that could go either way as there are times where Galactus and Odin have rather epic [fights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx1KF.jpg) without a clear winner. Although I'd say that if Galactus' power cosmic would be able to overpower the Odin force's enchantments on Mjolnir he'd be able to wield it. This would be like the unstoppable force immoveable object debate.

I also want to add that this is Galactus' and he could easily move the hammer about in a number of ways, but to actually wield the hammer in the same way that thor does would take more effort from him and may not be possible. There are also other things Galactus could do instead such as just creating a copy of the hammer with his own power but lacking a worthiness requirement or a different one. So technically Galactus would likely be able to move the hammer but not actually wield it, not that he would ever want or need to.

Comment: Accepted. I've been unable to find any examples of Galactus trying to do anything with Mjolnir, but we have to assume that if he can handily defeat Odin he would also be able to break or override the echantment.